# Java SplashScreen

Tags: java

I'm using NetBeans 6.1 as my primary IDE, in there I can't run this splash screen example which have given by the Sun (It throws an nullpointerExeption). But I can run this on command line using this arguments.

java -splash:filename.gif SplashDemo

I dont know how to inject command line arguments in NetBeans. Please someone help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SplashDemo extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    static void renderSplashFrame(Graphics2D g, int frame) {
        final String[] comps = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        g.fillRect(120, 140, 200, 40);
        g.setPaintMode();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Loading " + comps[(frame / 5) % 3] + "...", 120, 150);
    }

    public SplashDemo() {
        super("SplashScreen demo");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Menu m1 = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Exit");
        m1.add(mi1);
        mi1.addActionListener(this);
        this.addWindowListener(closeWindow);

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mb);
        mb.add(m1);
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        if (splash == null) {
            System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            renderSplashFrame(g, i);
            splash.update();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(90);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        splash.close();
        setVisible(true);
        toFront();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    private static WindowListener closeWindow = new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            e.getWindow().dispose();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SplashDemo test = new SplashDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the exception thrown ?

Comment: Does the splash screen work in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project properties (right click on a project, and choose properties). 
Choose "run" item from the Categories list.
There you can setup the arguments,  VM options etc.

Comment: Thanks but i know this already this is about for the whole project, I'm asking for a single class.

Comment: +1: works for me (under Eclipse) if I set the VM args correctly (ie. the -splash:imgfilename)  I'm not sure we understand what you mean by "I'm asking for a single class".  The splash screen is for loading the entire JVM + your app.  I don't think you can get it to pop up while your app is already running.